# Next JS You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: reactjs, next.js

i have this bug with Next JS

```
    ./node_modules/react-player/es6/ReactPlayer.jsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (140:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|       const { light, playIcon, previewTabIndex, oEmbedUrl } = this.props
|       return (
>         <Preview
|           url={url}
|           light={light}
```

Thank You